# How to read required attribute in C# 11 by reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, properties, required

In C# 11 Microsoft introduced required attribute for field and properties as member of class.
I need to read this attribute in reflection. How can I do it?
For example in class C1 and property P1 we need to read required attribute.

```cs
   class C1
   {
     public int required P1 { get; set; }

   }
   .
   ..
   Type targetType = typeof(C1);
   PropertyInfo propertyInfo = targetType.GetProperty("P1");
   propertyInfo.?????
```

propertyInfo.Attributes and enum System.Reflection.TypeAttributes does not have required item.

Answer (score 3):

Required members are decorated with [`RequiredMemberAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.requiredmemberattribute?view=net-7.0).

```
bool isRequired = typeof(C1).GetProperty("P1").GetCustomAttribute<RequiredMemberAttribute>() != null;
```

This was easy to discover [using SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTABAYQIwFgBQBvdcdygZjgCcBTARwFcBLU4OKgOwBc4AFJODOAcxKYG44AZz6CAvujFA==).